# Image Caption Alignment

Tags: floats, captions

I have two images of different heights and widths sat next to eachother on the page, and I'd like their captions to align. As it is currently, one caption is displaced vertically from the other.
My code goes as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[h]  
 \begin{minipage}[c]{0.49\textwidth}    
  \centering    
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1}    
  \caption{Caption 1 with citation 1.}    
  \label{fig:label1}    
 \end{minipage}    
\hspace*{0.1cm}    
 \begin{minipage}[c]{0.49\textwidth}    
  \centering    
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image2}    
  \caption{Caption 2 with citation 2.}    
  \label{fig:label2}    
 \end{minipage}    
\end{figure}
```

I've tried a couple of things, but none seem to work very well for me. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Edit: I've tried using [heightadjust=all]{floatrow} and the minipage[b] solution, but it does not seem to work. I've tried using both methods in a seperate document, but for the [heightadjust=all]{floatrow} I get an hbox error and the minipage[b] only works on some of my images.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Does any of the answers below solve your problem? If yes, please consider accepting it. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Comment: Sadly, this solution did not work for me. I just received an hbox overfull error, and it didn't include the images. Just a blank page with captions.

Answer (score 4):

Surely your images have different heights and that's why you notice that behavior.

I'll show you two options.

1. **Use the `floatrow` package**

   The `floatrow` package loaded with the option `heightadjust=all` automatically adjusts side by side figures and their captions.

   MWE:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage[heightadjust=all]{floatrow}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{figure}[!h]
      \begin{floatrow}
        \ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
            {\caption{Caption 1 with citation 1.}\label{fig:label1}}
        \ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image-b}}
            {\caption{Caption 2 with citation 2.}\label{fig:label2}}
      \end{floatrow}
   \end{figure}

   \end{document}
   ```

   Output:

   [image]
2. **Use `minipage`s with manual adjusting**

   Use the `[b]` specifier for `minipage`s instead of `[c]` and manually adjust the positioning of the images through some vertical space.

   MWE:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{graphicx}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{figure}[h]

   \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}

   \centering

   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}

   \caption{Caption 1 with citation 1.}

   \label{fig:label1}

   \end{minipage}%
   \hspace*{0.1cm}
   \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}

   \centering

   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image-b}

   \vspace*{48pt}

   \caption{Caption 2 with citation 2.}

   \label{fig:label2}

   \end{minipage}

   \end{figure}
   \end{document}
   ```

   Output:

   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Things look better with `subcaptionbox` from `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{first subfigure\label{fig:label1}}{\includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{second subfigure\label{fig:label2}}{\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth,height=1cm]{example-image-b}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably the OP wants two figures side by side, not two _sub_ figures...

Comment: @karlkoeller That may be one possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the exact results you get because I don't have the exact dimensions of your images. I suspect that the two images have unequal aspect ratios. Your minipages, including the captions, are horizontally centered. If you change that `[c]` for a `[b]`, they become bottom-aligned. Like this:

```
 \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
```